# Yii Framework syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, yii, syntax-error, unexpectendoffile

I know parse error and such things are programmers 101, but I cant find whats wrong with the file and the error "syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Following the tutorial helps me a lot getting to know php and Yii, but maybe the error isnt in that file, maybe somewere els. Hoppyfully you can help me with that.

```
<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Add User To Domain';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
$model->domain->name=>array('view','id'=>$model->domain->id),
'Add User',
);
$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'Back To Domain', 'url'=>array('view','id'=>$model->domain->id)),
);?>
<h1>Add User To <?php echo $model->domain->name; ?></h1>    
    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):?>
<div class="successMessage">
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
</div>
    <?phpendif; ?>

<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'username',
        'data'=>$usernames,
        'multiple'=>false,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('size'=>25),
    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'role'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'role', Project::getUserRoleOptions()); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'role'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Add User'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

//Error found thank you tinyByte

Another question:
Yii tells me that  `'data'=>$usernames,` is an *Undefined variable: usernames*
But in my UserForm Class php File I have this:

```
public function createUsernameList()
    {
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM tbl_user";
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $rows = $command->queryAll();
    //format it for use with auto complete widget
    $usernames = array();
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
    $usernames[]=$row['username'];
    }
    return $usernames;
    }
```

Do I have to create a public $usernames or something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: Please open a new question if you have another question.

Answer (score 4):

On line 15 you have to replace

`<?phpendif; ?>`

with

`<?php endif; ?>`

If you use an editor with syntax highlighting / validation (such as NetBeans, Eclipse or PhpStorm this would be highlighted for you)

I'm currently using PhpStorm